Difficulties solving this Berkley Math Tournament question
So i saw this nice question while scrolling instagram
Compute the sum of all positive integers $n$ , for which there exists a real number $x$ satisfying the following equation :
$(x + (n/x))^n = 20^k$ where k = 20
This question is from Berkley Math Tournament, but in the post it didnt specify which year so i coudnt find any step by step solution although the answer was given = 36
What i tried on my end was make three cases :

If $n > 20$ then $(x+(n/x))$ must be < than 20
If $n = 20$ then $(x + (n/x))$ must be 20
If $n < 20$ then $(x + (n/x))$ must be > than 20

I know this approach is wrong , idk i just feel its wrong
So please can anyone help explain the solution
Thanks

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Does x+n/x mean $x+(n/x)$, or does it mean $(x+n)/x$?

My apologies, i fixed it in edit

Welcome to Math SE. Thank you for your edit clarifying what Gerry Myerson asked about. However, I just posted an answer showing that the result for your equation is $325$ rather than $36$. Nonetheless, we do get $36$ if the RHS is $2^{20}$ instead of $20^{20}$. Please check to see whether or not that's the case.

I saw your answer john , thanks a lot for the explanation and i actually did check it many times in the instagram post it is given 20^(20) , a lot of people in the posts comments also raised similar point as yours but the page which posted is quite famous , i think you guys might know his Youtube or instagram channel name “ blackpenredpen”

@sumitdhiman Thanks for your response here. However, since there are $2$ other members apart from me who have previously commented to your question, then since you didn't use @ with my name, I didn't get pinged that you had replied to me. Please keep this in mind for any future comments directed to me (however, note that you don't need to do that with comments to my answer since I will always be pinged regardless).

@John Omielan Im very sorry, im quite new to this stack and math exchange site , im trying my best

@sumitdhiman No worries. You're doing fine, and you'll likely quite quickly learn the main various issues to be aware of.

It is from the 2023 Berkeley Math tournament, see here problem 11, it is indeed $2^{20}$, not $20^{20}$

Damn @leoli1 thanks for the link man .

Now you've introduced the "square bracket" notation, sumit, which is used for the "greatest integer" function, $[y]$ means the largest integer not exceeding $y$, e.g., $[\pi]=3$. You probably don't want that, it completely changes the problem.

Tried editing it again, wyt

Rather than your approach, there's
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(x + \frac{n}{x}\right)^n & = 20^{20} \\
x + \frac{n}{x} & = 20^{\frac{20}{n}} \\
x^2 + n & = \left(20^{\frac{20}{n}}\right)x \\
x^2 - \left(20^{\frac{20}{n}}\right)x + n & = 0 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
This is a quadratic equation in $x$, so there's a real solution $x$ if and only if the discriminant is non-negative, i.e.,
$$\left(20^{\frac{20}{n}}\right)^2 - 4n \ge 0 \;\;\to\;\; 20^{\frac{40}{n}} \ge 4n $$
Note that $20^{\frac{40}{n}}$ is strictly decreasing in positive integers $n$ while $4n$ is strictly increasing. At $n = 25$, we have $20^{\frac{40}{n}} = 20^{1.6} \approx 120.7$ and $4n = 100$, while with $n = 26$, then $20^{\frac{40}{n}} = 20^{\frac{20}{13}} \approx 100.4$ and $4n = 104$. Thus, all of the integers between $1$ and $25$, inclusive, work. This means their sum is
$$\frac{25 \times 26}{2} = 325$$
However, this doesn't match the result of $36$ that you provided. Note that, as leoli1's comment indicates, problem #$11$ of the $2023$ Berkeley Math tournament uses a RHS base of $2$ rather than $20$. The discriminant requirement then becomes
$$2^{\frac{40}{n}} \ge 4n$$
At $n = 8$, both sides are $32$, so $n \ge 9$ doesn't work. Thus, we then have that $n$ can be $1$ to $8$, inclusive, giving a sum of
$$\frac{8\times 9}{2} = 36$$

Thanks a ton . although i double checked and in the question it indeed is 20^(20)

@sumitdhiman You're welcome. However, this means that, for whatever reason(s), there's a mismatch between the problem statement and the stated solution value. Regardless, though, the approach I've shown in my answer is one method that does work for both cases, as well as in any such similar situations.

Your approach is incredible, however i have one more question if you can help me as im quite curious and excited to seek your help , my question is,  is this question solveable using the approach i stated in my question? Like can you play around with it to guide me

@sumitdhiman Regarding your additional question, it's not easily solvable using your approach since, although, one can show that all values less than or equal to $20$, and that some values $\gt 20$ also work, with this actually using something similar to what I did (i.e., a quadratic equation in $x$), I don't see any way to directly use that approach to determine what the upper limit would be. Also, regarding how this site works, you should try to ask just one question at a time, and post any new questions separately (possibly linking to the earlier question if they are closely related).
